# Pip install causes error. Can I debug it via pdb?

Tags: pdb

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5.2
```

Inside a virtualenv if I run python, I get Python 3.5.2.

The problem is:

```
(photoarchive) admin@simple_project:~/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/encodings$ pip install django-crequest
Collecting django-crequest
  Using cached django-crequest-2016.3.16.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-2qlcw5ux/django-crequest/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        license=open('LICENSE').read(),
      File "/home/admin/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 204: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2qlcw5ux/django-crequest/
```

Well, pip install ruins everything. By the way, without the virtualenv this package has installed via pip.

I'm stuck and don't know how to cope with this.

The only thing I can think of is to stop at that line 26 in ascii.py. 
This seems to be possible via pdb. I'm going to edit it and add pdb.set_trace() there. Then save the file.

Is it a good idea? The other question: is it possible without editing the file?

Comment: fwiw, a "fix" (if you maintain the package) is probably `io.open('LICENSE', encoding='UTF-8').read()` -- it is defaulting to ASCII most likely due to a missing `LANG` environment variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sure seems odd. It may be due to a corrupt download (which is being cached). To ensure a re-download, do

```
pip install --no-cache-dir django-crequest
```

If the same error occurs, try downloading the source code and edit `setup.py`:

```
mkdir tmp
pip download django-crequest --dest=./tmp
cd tmp
tar xfz django-crequest-2016.3.16.tar.gz
cd django-crequest-2016.3.16
sed -i '9 s/^/#/' setup.py  # comments out line 9 in setup.py
```

Now do the installation via the edited `setup.py`:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: It helped. But we don't know what in the licence is causing the trouble. Maybe I'll try to debug it via pdb.

Comment: I had no problem on Python 3.6. Also, the `LICENSE` file did not seem to contain any non-ascii characters. An easier method for further debugging might be to just read in the contents of the file (using `s = license=open('LICENSE', encoding='utf8').read()`) and then checking the code point of each character, e.g. `[ord(c) for c in s]`. Anything above 127 is outside the ascii range.

Comment: Without virtualenv everything installed fine. Tomorrow I'll experiment with what you suggested.

Comment: Nice one. To be noted that sometimes the problem can be in the pip cache, that is what happened in my case. The only workaround I found was to delete the cache dir, or to install using `pip install -U --no-cache-dir <package>`